# Can I improve this query?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, performance, t-sql, query-performance

```
SELECT * 
FROM   SameLogTable
WHERE  ID_Table IN (SELECT ID_Table-1
                    FROM   SameLogTable
                    WHERE  <SameCondition>) OR
       ID_Table IN (SELECT ID_Table
                    FROM   SameLogTable
                    WHERE  <SameCondition>) OR
       ID_Table IN (SELECT ID_Table+1
                    FROM   SameLogTable
                    WHERE  <SameCondition>)
```

This query runs on a Logging Table, and I want to select particular events, but also the event preceding and following those events.
This solution feels ugly and inefficient, what would be the better way to write the for this?

Example: If I am interested in lines with ID 4, and 23 of a LogTable, I want to get the following result:

```
ID    Column1    Column2    ...
3     ...        ...
4     ...        ...
5     ...        ...
22    ...        ...
23    ...        ...
24    ...        ...
```

These are all lines from the Same LogTable, except I specify Lines 4 and 23 using a WHERE , and I want the Select to automatically return rows 3,5 for 4 and rows 22, 24 for 23.

---

**To Summarize the results:**

```
MyQuery:     16s
UNION ALL:    4s
Join:        ~0s
```

Thanks for the replies!

Comment: Do an inner join between the two tables and put the conditions in the where clause?

Comment: You're just duplicating the contents of col1-colN and adding +/-1 to the ID?

Comment: Give us examples of the `<Condition>`. Is it always equality, like `id = 4` or a list check like `id IN (4.23,...)`? Or it can be more complicated?

Comment: And which version of SQL-Server is this for? If for 2012, `LEAD()` and `LAG()` functions may help to produce a better plan.

Comment: There is only 1 Table with Logs
The Rows already exist in the log, I need to select a particular Row, as well as the (complete!)rows before and after it.
@ypercube SQL-Server 2008 R2, the <Condition> could be anything, but is the Same for each of the Selects Where I get the different IDs. ex: WHERE LogDateTime IN <DateTime>, or WHERE LogTrigger = <TriggerName>

Comment: Not sure if this would improve things, but what about `id_table in (select ID_Table-1 from samelogtable union all select ID_Table from samelogtable union all select ID_Table+1 from samelogtable)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name UNION improved the query, instead of 16 sec it now runs 4 sec. Guess you can put it as an answer, but I'm curious if there is yet a better way : P

Comment: ...ideally running the  <Condition> filter on the table 1 time instead of 3

Comment: If `id` is `IDENTITY` it is not guaranteed that the values won't have gaps. So your `+1`/`-1` might miss the actual next/previous row.

Comment: @MartinSmith then I'd have to use something like Min(ID) > ID and Max(ID) < ID, instead of ID+1 / ID-1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that `ID` is the primary key of the table (or has a unique constraint), you can use this variant:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM   SameLogTable AS t
  JOIN ( SELECT id
         FROM   SameLogTable 
         WHERE  <SameCondition>
       ) AS c
       ON t.id = c.id -1
       OR t.id = c.id
       OR t.id = c.id +1 ;
```

**Note:** if the `id` have gaps, which is very probable, the above will not work as expected and neither will your original query. `ROW_NUMBER()` can help you for that:

```
; WITH cte AS
( SELECT t.*,
         rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.id)
  FROM   SameLogTable AS t
) 
SELECT t.*
FROM   cte AS t
  JOIN ( SELECT rn
         FROM   cte 
         WHERE  <SameCondition>
       ) AS c
       ON t.rn = c.rn - 1
       OR t.rn = c.rn
       OR t.rn = c.rn + 1 ;
```

Comment: Nice, this is fast... didn't think a Join could work so nicely

Answer (score 2):

On solution is to use a `UNION ALL` so you only need a single sub-query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   SameLogTable
WHERE  ID_Table in (SELECT ID_Table-1
                    FROM   SameLogTable
                    WHERE  <SameCondition>
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT ID_Table
                    FROM   SameLogTable
                    WHERE  <SameCondition>
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT ID_Table+1
                    FROM   SameLogTable
                    WHERE  <SameCondition>)
```